# How to print requested number of lines

Tags: python

I am trying to code a `more` function.

I need to:

- make the program pause
- ask for the number of additional lines to be printed
- print that number of lines
- pause again.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys, fileinput
i=0
for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line.rstrip())
    i=i+1
    if i==20:
        what=input("<--Enter the # of additional lines you wish to print/q to Quit -->")
    if what=="q":
        exit()
    else:
        if str.isdigit(what):
            print(line.rstip[i:i+int(what)]
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your code? Tell us what you would expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    fh = f.read()
    lines = fh.splitlines()
    lines_so_far = 0
    while lines_so_far < len(lines):
        batch_count = 0
        lines_requested = int(input('How many lines to print?'))
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
            batch_count += 1
            lines_so_far += 1
            if batch_count == lines_requested and lines_so_far < len(lines):
                printmore = input ('Print more lines: Y or N?')
                if printmore == 'Y':
                    batch_count = 0
                    lines_requested = int(input('How many lines?'))
                else:
                    lines_so_far = len(lines)
                    break
    print ('\n Done Printing')
```